How to configure Nginx Proxy Manager to serve a project on port 3000 with a specific path?
I'm using Nginx Proxy Manager to manage my reverse proxies, and I have a project running on port 3000. I want to access this project through a URL like https://www.example.com/planka. I added the proxy host in Nginx Proxy Manager, but I'm not sure how to configure it properly to achieve this.
Here are the details of my setup:
Nginx Proxy Manager: Version X.X
Project: Running on port 3000
Desired URL: https://www.example.com/planka
Steps I've taken:
Added a new Proxy Host in Nginx Proxy Manager with the following settings:

Domain Names: www.example.com
Scheme: http
Forward Hostname / IP: here i have ip address
Forward Port: 3000
Enable Websockets Support: Checked
Block Common Exploits: Checked
SSL: Enabled, Force SSL

In the Advanced tab, I added the following configuration (not sure if this is correct):
location /planka/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

}
However, when I navigate to https://www.example.com/planka, I get a 404 error or the application doesn't load correctly.
My questions:
Is the configuration in the Advanced tab correct?
Do I need to modify any other settings in Nginx Proxy Manager to make this work?
Are there any additional steps required to ensure the project is served correctly under the /planka path?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
